# Vuex with Nuxt - Unknown Action Type:

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I am trying to move my local methods to a VueX Store. Im using nuxt.js so the store format is a bit different than usual. When I try to call my store action, i get "vuex unknown action type: fetchProducts". Its gotta be something to do with how im calling the store, but I havent quite figured it out.

So, Nuxt uses the store folder system, and I call to import map actions -
`import { mapActions } from 'vuex';`

then in my methods, I list map actions alongside the directory the method exists in an index.js file.

```
          ...mapActions('RyansBag/Inventory', [
            'fetchProducts',
        ]),
```

in the same methods, I request to start pulling the data from the store from this method, which is mounted.

```
        async getProducts(){
        this.TableData.isLoading = true;
        await this.$store.dispatch('fetchProducts', this.options);
        this.TableData.isLoading = false;
      },
```

my understanding is in nuxt i dont have to call an action by its module name - which nothing is in module - I think? Unless store folder system in nuxt is considered modules which I may have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

for the fetch request, it should have been this.fetchProducts() instead of a string reference. Fixed. :)